# HttpOnly cookie not saved in browser

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js, strapi, httponly

I have a problem with HttpOnly cookie, I have a custom auth API that returns me a HttpOnly cookie with a token when I login, but the problem is, when i make another request in front with Axios using withCredentials, the cookie is not send in the headers and I can't understand why.

I'm using NextJs as a front-end and strapi for the back-end

Here is the request to the API, which returns me the cookie
[image: Here is the request to the API, which returns me the cookie]

And here is a request that i do just after
[image: And here is a request that i do just after]

Here is the code that create the second request

```
await axios.get(param.endpoints.getMe, {withCredentials: true})
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Solution**

The problem was that i forgot to add "withCredentials: true" to the login request.

I passed 4 hours on this.

I hate myself

Comment: After spending a whole afternoon trying to figure it out, I hate myself too. But thanks. This worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having the same issue, i can confirm that you need to set withCredentials: true on the axios request when logging in, for it to work. Just add it to every request to be safe...